# send files from android app (Retrofit) to server (Spring ) error

Tags: java, android, file-upload, retrofit2

I try to send files from my app to a server using this method `uploadFileClass`, and I get **error code response** : **404**, this  the server code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("description") String description,
                                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            bytes = file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error processing uploaded file"+ e.getMessage());
        }
        return "file upload received! Name:[" + description + "] Size:["
                + bytes.length + "]";
    } else {
        return "file upload failed!";
    }
}
```

in my application android I display some icones in notification bar, so this my code :

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        ApiService service = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://192.168.1.2:8080").client(client).build().create(ApiService.class);

  File file = new File(audit.getPath());

                RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
                RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "upload_test");
                retrofit2.Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> req = service.postImage(body, name);
                req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

this is my infterface :

```
public interface ApiService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/")
    Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);
}
```

Comment: do you have the internet permissions? are you able to access your server from the mobile browser for example?

Comment: I saw all the response in stackover flow before posting my question, I have the permission internet bro, Yes I had access

Comment: Try changing your request code, as server is expecting something with key name "description", and your are sending "upload_test".
Do this `MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), reqFile);
                RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "description");`